# ionic , phonegap and android studio

Tags: cordova, android-studio, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I want to know how build an hybrid mobile app using ionic and phonegap and android studio to deploy the project. I know how to create projects individually in each of this but how to integrate them. I am naive to mobile development. Can anyone please guide how to go further.
I have added the phonegap project in my android studio and copied the ionic files in android studio direct. But it is not working as desired.

Comment: Which Operating System you are using?

Comment: OS X Yosemite version

Comment: You can create your projects in sublime editor na.. and there you can check the project from terminal by typing the cmd as ionic run android/ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Terminal and go to the root of your ionic project, add Android platform if not already done.

```
ionic platform add android
```

Then build android project

```
ionic build android
```

The project is created in the folder platforms/android.
Open Android Studio and select 'Import project...', select the Android project folder from above and you should be good to go.